# How to tackle variables that may not be set when using blade template engine to build forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Ok, so a long title, but apologies, he only way to describe it without getting the wrong kind of answer.

So, the scenario....

I am creating a site which has a search form of sorts in the header, and therefore on every page. I would like it to retain its previous variables when being used for user convenience, for my convenience I have built the form into the default layout, to save recreating many instances of it.

default.blade.php (Heres the form, with unnecessary markup removed)

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search')) }}
{{ Form::select('model', Photo::getAvailableModels(true), $model) }}
{{ Form::select('colour', Photo::getAvailableColours(true), $colour) }}
{{ Form::submit('Go') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The $model & $colour are variables I am capturing during the post. The problem is, I am getting unset variable errors from Blade on any pages where the user hasn't posted to, so I am literally having to preset them in almost every route or controller across my entire site, just to prevent the errors.

In essence, the system works fine as long as the user is posting, if someone visits the site using a direct link its basically useless.

Obviously I can not have the search form be set to the previously searched results, but that would be bad practice from a usability point of view.

Am I missing something here, surely there has to be a simple solution to this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view composer for your highly used variables:

```
View::composer(['store.index', 'products.*'], function($view)
{

    $model = Input::get('model') ?: 'modelX';
    $colour = Input::get('colour') ?: 'colourY';

    $view->with('model', $model);
    $view->with('colour', $colour);

});
```

Laravel will send those variables to your views automatically, every time someone hit one of them.

You can put that in your routes file, filters file or, like, me, create a app/composers.php and load by adding

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

To your app/start/global.php.

Comment: Thanks, a very clean solution, certainly seems to offer a good level of re-usability. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether variables are set or not with PHP [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search')) }}

@if (isset($model) && isset($colour))
    {{ Form::select('model', Photo::getAvailableModels(true), $model) }}
    {{ Form::select('colour', Photo::getAvailableColours(true), $colour) }}
@else
    {{ Form::select('model', Photo::getAvailableModels(true)) }}
    {{ Form::select('colour', Photo::getAvailableColours(true)) }}
@endif

{{ Form::submit('Go') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Or, if your form fields are optional and you need to check separately:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search')) }}
@if (isset($model))
    {{ Form::select('model', Photo::getAvailableModels(true), $model) }}
@else
    {{ Form::select('model', Photo::getAvailableModels(true)) }}
@endif

@if (isset($colour))
    {{ Form::select('colour', Photo::getAvailableColours(true), $colour) }}
@else
    {{ Form::select('colour', Photo::getAvailableColours(true)) }}
@endif

{{ Form::submit('Go') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Although this would work, It just doesn't seem as elegant as the solution offered by Antonio. However, still a very viable answer, thanks.

Comment: Agree! Antonio's answer is the way to go. But it doesn't harm to know all posibilities :)

Comment: Manuel, the problem I see with yours is that views should not be aware of models existence, at least for me, this is a don't inside a view: `Photo::`.

Comment: Actually, I've left that code as the OP had it. The only thing I was showing here is how to check for variable existence in blade templates, which is the title of the question. Of course, these variables should not come from the data layer, but that wasn't the point of the answer.

Comment: Yeah, feel free to downvote instead of reading things first. Yay!